# How to set up a .NET 7 C# rate limiter per user if the user id is stored ONLY in the entity in the request body?

Tags: c#, rate-limiting, .net-7.0

There is an API that accepts an entity with a previously unknown ID. I need to configure the rate limiter so that entities with the same ID get into the queue. I figured out how to create a window and a queue. How to make a separate queue for each ID?

The entity is a JSON file. The ID is inside the file.

The following is written, but this forms one queue:

```
services.AddRateLimiter(options => options
            .AddFixedWindowLimiter(policyName: "UserPolicy", options =>
            {
                options.PermitLimit = 1;
                options.Window = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                options.QueueProcessingOrder = QueueProcessingOrder.OldestFirst;
                options.QueueLimit = 3;
            }));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [`PartitionedRateLimiter`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-rate-limiting-for-dotnet/#partitionedratelimiter). Something along these lines (not tested):

```cs
builder.Services.AddRateLimiter(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("myRateLimiter1", context =>
    {
        var request = context.Request;
        var partitionKey = "";
        if (request.Method == HttpMethods.Post && request.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            request.EnableBuffering();
            var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];
            request.Body.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            //get body string here...
            var requestContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            // get partition key here... partitionKey = ... 
            request.Body.Position = 0;  //rewinding the stream to 0
        }
        return RateLimitPartition.GetFixedWindowLimiter(
            partitionKey: partitionKey,
            factory: partition => new FixedWindowRateLimiterOptions
            {
                PermitLimit = 1,
                Window = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                QueueProcessingOrder = QueueProcessingOrder.OldestFirst,
                QueueLimit = 3
            });
    });
});
```

Though I would suggest to consider passing Id in some other way (headers) or resolve the limiter on the handler/BL level.